# Hyperledger Composer Query an Asset's parameter

Tags: javascript, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have defined my hyperledger composer model file as such;

```
namespace org.acme.myNetwork

asset Asset identified by assetId {
 o String assetId
 --> Owner owner
 o String assetStatus
}

participant Owner identified by ownerId {
 o String ownerId
 o String ownerName
 o String ownerStatus
}
```

I would like to query the Owner of an asset that has the value of assetStatus = "invalid". I've read on the [hyperledger composer query language](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/query-language.html) documentation and they seem to only have examples where an individual could query an asset or participant, but it does not show an example of how to query a parameter of an asset or participant.

```
 query selectAsset {
  description: "Select Asset"
  statement: SELECT org.acme.myNetwork.Asset
              WHERE assetStatus == "invalid"
 }

 query selectAssetParameter {
  description: "Select Asset Parameter"
  statement: SELECT org.acme.myNetwork.Asset.owner
              WHERE assetStatus == "invalid"
 }
```

The first example of the query above is valid, but the second query written would throw this error in playground:

`Error found!
t: Namespace is not defined for type org.acme.myNetwork.Asset.owner`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I pasted your model into Composer Playground and received an error with the name of your Asset saying `Asset` was a reserved word - if you were able to deploy this model using a different method I would like to know to raise an Issue.  I used an asset name of `Ass1` for my test.

With your query you need to have parenthesis round the where condition e.g. `WHERE (assetStatus == "invalid")`

To answer your question - you have created a query against a property (assetStatus), but the result set will always be a list of *complete assets*, not just an individual property (this is different to a SQL select).

Your query will return assets that match 'invalid', and the owner will be returned as a resource reference. e.g. `"owner": "resource:org.acme.myNetwork.Owner#AA1"`

If you want to get all the properties of the Owner, not just the ID, then you will have to write a second query, or perform a GET request on the Owner registry.  As an alternative you could use a *filter* on GET request to the Ass1 (Asset) registry which would "resolve" the owner.

So with this filter: `{"where":{"assetStatus":"invalid"}, "include":"resolve"}` on this endpoint `/api/Ass1` using a GET request you would see this result:

```
  {
   "$class": "org.acme.myNetwork.Ass1",
    "assetId": "WILL01",
    "owner": {
      "$class": "org.acme.myNetwork.Owner",
      "ownerId": "AA1",
      "ownerName": "Albert",
      "ownerStatus": "VALID"
    },
    "assetStatus": "invalid"
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my use of the "Asset" keyword and the query without the () brackets, I forgot that i'm not on the composer playground and nobody was checking my definitions